# Remove array 0 in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, array-filter

I have 2 product id and my code is:

```
$Final=array();
foreach ($ids as $me)
   {
     $op=DB::table('product')->where(['id'=>$me])->get();
     //$Final[]= $op;
      array_push($Final,$op);
   }
```

This code returns:

```
 array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=15)
          'id' => string '34' (length=2)
          'title' => string 'گوسفند' (length=12)
          'title_url' => string 'sheep' (length=5)
          'code' => string 'eerer' (length=5)
          'code_url' => string 'eerer' (length=5)
          'content' => string '<p>sheep</p>
' (length=14)
          'cat' => string '68' (length=2)
          'price' => string '50000' (length=5)
          'product_state' => string '1' (length=1)
          'date' => string '' (length=0)
          'order_number' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Special' => string '0' (length=1)
          'View' => string '0' (length=1)
          'number_product' => string '1' (length=1)
          'discounts' => string '' (length=0)
```

I need to remove

```
array (size=2) 0 => array (size=1) 0 => 
$ids => filter id
```

for get product number for example (22,34)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you should try this.

```
$Final=array();
foreach ($ids as $me){
    $op=DB::table('product')->where(['id'=>$me])->get();

    if($op) {

        array_push($Final,$op[0]);
    }
}
```

Then you will get these values.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=15)
        'id' => string '34' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=15)
        'id' => string '22' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Any framework then framwork provide us some methods to run query with where in to get all the records in single query.

```
$op=DB::table('product')->whereIn('id'=>$ids)->get();
```

you will get array of collection for all the products.